# Globally overwrite 3rd party service/factory in angular app

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to **globally** decorate/overwrite a 3rd party service that is defined through a factory. I can decorate the service just fine in my own module and it uses my implementation in my module but I need to change it's behaviour in the 3rd party module as well (so *all* calls use my implementation).

I tried to move the decoration in a config method of the 3rd party module (before my module gets defined) but this has no effect.

```
angular.module("3rd-party").config(["$provide", function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("3rd-party-service", ["$delegate", function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.methodToOverwrite = function () {
            console.log("...");
        };

        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```

Thanks for any advice!